# Search database not working when using ajax

Tags: java, sql, ajax, jsp

I am using ajax for real-time search in my database and also JSP works as my server code.But when I try running the application,the search results do not come out.Please is anything wrong with my ajax code.
 Ajax code

```
function Search(){
    if (window.XMLHTTPRequest){

    xmlresults = new XMLHttRequest();    
 }else{
     xmlresults = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 }
 xmlresults.onreadystatechange = function (){
     if(xmlresults.readyState == 4 && xmlresults.status == 200){

         document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = xmlresults.responseText;
     }
 }
 xmlresults.open('GET','searchR.jsp?seb='+ document.form1.seb.value,true);
 xmlresults.send();

}
```

JSP code that does the querying of the database depending on what is entered into search box.Try-catch code below,after declaring my variables and importing java.sql.* package.

```
try{
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/search","root","root");

            query = "select * from result";
          // query = "select * from result where seb like '"+seb+"%'";
          ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
          rs = ps.executeQuery();

          if(rs.next()){
           %>
           <div >
               <%=rs.getString("seb")%>
           </div>     
       <%    
           }

    }catch(Exception e){
       out.println("Error "+e);
    }
%>
```

Page that does the display of the search query.I am using the form element.

```
<form name="form1"  id="form1" method="GET">
        <table width="638" height="38" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
              <input name="seb" type="text" id="seb" size="75" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Enter into Search box" style="line-height: 25px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 15px; border-radius: 9px; box-shadow: #F3F3F3 0.1em 0.1em 0.3em 0.1em; border-color: #F5F5F5;" onKeyUp="Search();">
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>              <input type="submit" name="Search" id="Search" value="Search" style="height:30px;"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
         <table width="588" border="0">
            <div id="searchResults">

            </div>
        </table>
```

Please note that the name of the JSP code that does the querying of the database is searchR.jsp which is also specified/called in the ajax code and also the id of the text-field is seb,the id of the div tag that shows after input into the search text-field is searchResults which is also used in the ajax code.I hope its clear and my error can be pointed out to me.Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is even worth to solve it using this approach. Because you are trying to use JSP what is usually done by service (i.e. calling database). In MVC pattern, JSP is a View and should remain as such.

Comment: What I would have done is placing an `alert()` inside the function `onreadystatechange()` to check if `state 4` and `status 200` really happened. if yes then checking the `responsetext` in `alert()`. If alert would come blank, then sending that particular request through browser to see the result. I told only about if-part of 3 conditions, the else cases also exist. try debuging this way. Your code seems to be ok except not using MVC pattern